# Names not populating from disassembly to decompiler

Tags: ida, idapython, idapro-sdk, ida-plugin

I am writing a script in IDA Pro. I noticed that when I rename functions with "n" in the *disassembly* view, that same function is not being renamed in the *decompilation*.

I have never noticed this before. Is this normal operating behavior? If so, how can you automatically transfer the names from the disassembly view to the decompilation view?

(I have notice this also happens when I rename functions with a script).

Comment: Have you tried to just decompile it again?

Comment: I have, my first instinct was to close the decompilation view, and then press tab again. It still doesn't show up.

Comment: It seems like it works when I close/reopen IDA Pro --  I guess that's one way to do it. :/

Comment: As far as I remember TAB does trigger the decompilation if it already has been decompiled. Press F5 to force decompilation.

Answer (score 2):

If you rename things outside of pseudocode view, it’s not updated automatically and you need to press <kbd>F5</kbd>to refresh decompilation with current data.